# troubleshoot excel flickering in formula window after vba calculate event

Tags: vba, excel

### Symptoms

After completing a VBA macro that runs whenever a calculation event occurs, my workbook enters a strange semi-lock state. The symptoms are:

1. When highlighting any cell with contents, the formula bar or window flickers several times per second.
2. I can enter formulas and formula arrays in any blank cell and calculation proceeds as normal, although flickering continues.
3. Switching between auto/manual calculate has no effect on the flickering.
4. The array formulas associated with the calculation event take on a strange property:  While editing them in the formula bar, if I press `ENTER` nothing happens.  Normally for an array formula I would get an error, but for these, the cursor just stays in the formula editing window unless I press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.   See below for relevant details on the application.

### For context:

My application is a VBA add-in that uses UDF's to pull read-only data from a remote MySQL server.  The workflow involves piggy-backing on the calculate event in order to get around the fact that excel UDF's can't alter the size of the formula that is calling them.  The process goes:

1. user enters formula
2. formula creates a 'query' item that is stored in a global collection
3. upon calculation, a subroutine processes all the queries, sends SQL queries to the remote database, receives the response, resizes the formula region to fit the size of the returned data, and stores the returned data in another global collection
4. when the calling region is resized, the formula function automatically runs again.  This time, it sees that data is waiting in the second global collection and that the data is the right size, and it writes the data to the worksheet, preserving the formula

Based on the debug window, it looks like my calculate event has finished when the flickering begins to occur.  All of my global collections are empty.  I'm not sure what the application is doing when it locks in this way or how to get more data on the problem.  It only occurs occasionally.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Comment: A shot in the dark: `When highlighting any cell with contents, the formula bar or window flickers several times per second` Check the Add-In Code. Is there a code there `Worksheet_SelectionChange` or `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`

Comment: No, I'm not using either of those.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it helps someone who has the same or similar problem. In my case there were no formulas in workbook and no calculate events. Still - after macro executed, values populated by the macro in formula window were flickering.

After debugging, it came out that on line with array paste, macro was repeatedly going back to start of procedure, while pasting only part of data. After I fixed calculation of array values, so that arguments for timeserial functions were correct, pasting complete array succeeded without retreating to start of sub.